# got "incorrect arity 1 for clojurewerkz.quartzite.jobs/of-type" when use the cron example of quartzite?

Tags: clojure, quartzite

I try to use the cron example as the get start page:
http://clojurequartz.info/articles/getting_started.html

```
(defjob NoOpJob
[ctx]
(comment "Does nothing"))

(defn -main
[& m]
(let [s   (-> (qs/initialize) qs/start)
    job (j/build
          (j/of-type NoOpJob)
          (j/with-identity (j/key "jobs.noop.1")))
    trigger (t/build
              (t/with-identity (t/key "triggers.1"))
              (t/start-now)
              (t/with-schedule (schedule
                                 (cron-schedule "0 0 15 ? * 5"))))]
(qs/schedule s job trigger)))
```

the intellij give me the "incorrect arity 1 for clojurewerkz.quartzite.jobs/of-type" at line

```
(j/of-type NoOpJob)
```

I check the api doc:
http://reference.clojurequartz.info/clojurewerkz.quartzite.jobs.html#var-of-type

the function of type is have two arity:

```
(of-type jb clazz)
```

is there something wrong?Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`j/build`](https://github.com/michaelklishin/quartzite/blob/de96a2ae95ec232df3e24cf10f4e5ff33af3553b/src/clojure/clojurewerkz/quartzite/jobs.clj#L73-L76) is a macro, that "injects" the first argument (via the the threading macro `->`):

> ```clj
> (defmacro ^JobDetail build
>   [& body]
>   `(let [jb# (JobBuilder/newJob)]
>      (finalize (-> jb# ~@body))))
> ```

Your IDE is wrongfully claiming an error here.  The code most likely compiles and runs fine.